# How to control services start-up sequence in docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: devops

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      mongodb:
        image: hedge-mongo:1.0
        container_name: mongodb
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
        networks:
          - appNetwork
      service-A:
        image: service-A:1.0
        container_name: service-A
        ports:
          - "3030:3030"
        networks:
          - appNetwork
        depends_on:
          - mongodb   
      service-B:
        image: service-B:1.0
        container_name: service-B
        ports:
          - "4200:4200"
        networks:
          - appNetwork
      service-C:
        image: service-C:1.0
        container_name: service-C
        ports:
          - "8082:8082"
       networks:
      - appNetwork 
   networks:
    appNetwork:
    external: true
```

In above file service-A and service-C are trying to connect to MongoDB
Issue:
In above file service-A and service-C are getting connected to MongoDB before MongoDB is up
so, I want to run service-A and service-C after MongoDB is up completely.
I tried adding depends-on for service-A and service-C

```
service-A:
    image: service-A:1.0
    container_name: service-A
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    networks:
      - appNetwork
    depends_on:
      - mongodb   

  service-C:
    image: service-C:1.0
    container_name: service-C
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    networks:
      - appNetwork 
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

still, it did not work out sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't so it's not reliable.
I want to make sure my other services are up only after MongoDB is up.

Answer (score 1):

that is a race condition, you're services is trying to start at the same time, thats why you got a result of sometimes it success and sometimes its not.. here an example on how to solve the race condition..

[example 1](http://www.blog.labouardy.com/preventing-race-conditions-in-docker/)

[example 2](https://8thlight.com/blog/dariusz-pasciak/2016/10/17/docker-compose-wait-for-dependencies.html)

Comment: sure..glad could help. .if it solve your question, consider accepting the answer.. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379998/job-chaining-in-jenkins-after-bringing-up-docker-containers can you answer this question as well ?